# How do you download PIP?

Tags: python, pip

So i'm trying to download pip but when i go to the website ( https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py ) it just shows a script and does not download anything.

I'm a beginner

Comment: Run the script through python

Comment: If you have python 3.4 or later it is included by default in the python installer

Comment: Right-click, save link as, save as a `get-pip.py`. Run with python.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install pip using the Python Installer.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows**

Right click on https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and save as..
go to where the file is and run it with python in the cmd.

```
python get-pip.py
```

Then you can check the version typing

`pip --version`

and you can verify the installation typing

```
pip help
```

If you get an error you can check here too

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows

*I hope it can help*